# Create a 7zip file for every subdirectory to a output path from input path in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, 7zip

1. I have an input path that contains an unknown number of
   subdirectories.
2. I want to use 7zip to zip each of them and the zip file will be in the selected output path.

Below is the concept of this program.

[image]

Below is the 7zip code I try to achieve the result, but no idea how to do.

```
 string source = textBoxInput.Text + "\\*";                
 string target = Path.Combine(tBoxOutput.Text, source + DateTime.Now.ToString());

 foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(source))
 {
   _sevenZip.CreateZipFile(folder, target);
 }
```

Below is the 7z in command line I use to this program.

```
try
{
  ProcessStartInfo zipProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
  zipProcess.FileName = @"E:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
  zipProcess.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";
        zipProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        Process zip = Process.Start(zipProcess);
        zip.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
   Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: let me know if my answer not good for you, and I will fix it

Comment: @DorLugasi Thanks for always support, it works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember helping you once with that question , i guess my answer was not to your satisfaction,
I've tried better this time:

this is the window:

[image]

these are the folders I used, just like in your example:

[image]
'choose source' and 'choose target' button opens a folder dialog

you were in the right direction, a for loop that runs over the subdirectories. i guess the hard part was getting the correct names. you just need to make sure that the target name would have a ".7z" extension.

and the code is fairly simple:

```
string zipProgramPath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void CreateZipFile(string sourceName, string targetName)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo zipProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
        zipProcess.FileName = zipProgramPath; // select the 7zip program to start
        zipProcess.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";
        zipProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        zipProcess.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process zip = Process.Start(zipProcess);
        zip.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void btnBrowseSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            lblSource.Text = fbd.SelectedPath; //label next to the button
        }
    }

}
private void btnBrowseTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            lblTarget.Text = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString(); //label next to the button
        }
    }
}

private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSource.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTarget.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Choose input directory and output directory");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(lblSource.Text))
        {
            string folderName= Path.GetFileName(folder);
            string targetName = Path.Combine(lblTarget.Text, folderName+ ".7z" );
            CreateZipFile(folder, targetName);
        }
    }
}
```

so after choosing the right directories, and pressing execute

[image]

the result is as required :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PowerShell script will do the same. SourceFolders will have your test, test1, test2 folders. Compressed files will gets stored into C:\DestinationFolder.  You just have run this script from PowerShell command prompt.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

$sourcefolders = Get-ChildItem "C:\SourceFolders"
$outputfolder = "C:\DestinationFolder"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $sourcefolders.Count; $i++) {

$folderPathToCompress = $sourcefolders[$i].FullName 
$compressFileName = $sourcefolders[$i].Name

"Compressing folder ="+$folderPathToCompress;

.\7z a -t7z $outputfolder\$compressFileName".7z" $folderPathToCompress

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is an alternative way if i use power shell next time.